# How to create module for desktop application?

Tags: c#, desktop-application, sharpdevelop

In C# language and using sharpdevelop I was wondering how I can create a desktop application that loads features or forms only when requested and not at software boot, something like libraries?

Comment: you are looking for pluggable architecture.check link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4691/Plugin-Architecture-using-C

Answer (score 0):

If you compile your features into separate assemblies, they will not be loaded by the runtime until the first time they are used.

If you want more control, you can use `Assembly.Load` and reflection to pick what you want to load at runtime.